# How to click on a link on a javascript app on IE using VBS

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Hi I am trying to click on a Link and i think it is on javascript

i have used ie.document.getElementById("WOTRACK_APP").click or getElementsByName
but it kept telling me object required.

I am trying to click on the "Work Order Tracking". And the id is WOTRACK_APP
but the problem is when i read the source code, WOTRACK_APP is a sub of WO_MODULE. So I am having difficulties to get to WOTRACK_APP.

Do i need to trigger other commands to click on the link?

This is part of the source code

```
m9bc09af3_ncnavSections["m7f8f3e49_ns"]=
{"height":"","state":statem7f8f3e49_ns,"loaded":false};
m9bc09af3_ncnavSectionsOrder.push("m7f8f3e49_ns");
fillNavSection({"menu":{"id":"menu0nsaag-ns","mxevent":"changeapp","items":
{"id":"WO_MODULE","sub":{"id":"10","mxevent":"changeapp","items":
[{"id":"WOTRACK_APP","text":"Work Order Tracking","eventvalue":"WOTRACK"},
{"id":"LABREP_APP","text":"Labor Reporting","eventvalue":"LABREP"},
{"id":"WORKMAN_APP","text":"Assignment 
Manager","eventvalue":"WORKMAN"},{"id":"OTREP_APP","text":"Overtime 
Reporting","eventvalue":"OTREP"}],"type":1,"openat":null},"text":"Work 
Orders","image":"modimg_wo.gif"}],"type":1,"openat":null}},  
"labelledBy":"m7f8f3e49_ns_label","args":{"content":{"events": 
dojo.toJson([{"navSectionId":"m7f8f3e49_ns","containerId" : 
"m9bc09af3_nc","classname":"ns_goto","showImages" : "true","isQuery" : 
"false","render" : "true"}])}}});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Reams of code does not help us at all. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have edit my post and remove some of the codes

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear, do you want to make a javascript or a VisualBasic Script app?
A link is normaly:

```
 <a href='url'>Link text</a>.
```

When using document.getelementbyid, you don't need to specify ie before (and it will crash in vbs because it doesn't use ie object).

What do you need to do exatly and why do you need both javascript and VBScrip?

You wrote that you try to click on a link but it can mean everything...

Comment: I am trying to make a VBScript and i have Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"). The normal stuff to open IE and navigate to the website i want. I am trying to click on a link that is "Work Order Tracking" and it's ID is "WOTRACK_APP". The website is a javascript webclient.

Comment: Have you try «ie.Navigate "http://www.link.com/"»  inside a function (->function navigate(link))? for ie.document.getelementbyid... just try document.getelementbyid

Comment: Sorry I am not really familiar with vbscript. I did use IE.navigate "link" but i am not really sure when you say inside a function

Comment: For example: <inpput type='button' onclick='goToLink('google.com')'>

VBS:
function goToLink(link)
      ie.navigate link
end Function